# Jquery lazy load is not working properly with jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, lazy-loading

I am trying to add jquery lazy load with jquery datatable. But the problem occurs when data goes to paginated page, jquery lazy load cannot process other pages image

```
@foreach($products as $product)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$i++}}</td>
                                <td width="10%">
                                    <img width="90%" class='lazy' data-src="/storage/{{explode(',',$product->images)[0]}}">
                                </td>
                                <td>{{$product->p_name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$product->sku}}</td>
                                <td><b>{{$product->currency == "dollar"?'$':$product->currency}}</b>{{$product->price}}</td>
                                <td>{{$product->quantity}}</td>
                                <td>{{$product->active == true?'Enable':'Disable'}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{route('product.show', $product->id)}}" class="btn btn-small waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
@endforeach

@section('js')
<script src="{{asset('plugins/datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src='{{asset('plugins/jquery/jquery.lazy.min.js')}}'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#table").dataTable();
        $('select').formSelect();
    });
    $(function() {
        $('.lazy').lazy();
    });
</script>
```

@endsection

Jquery datatable first page

[image: Jquery datatable first page]

Jquery databable second page

[image: Jquery databable second page]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add callback options to your dataTable like:

```
$("#table").dataTable({
    drawCallback: function(settings){
        $('.lazy').lazy();
    }
});
```